# Ubuntu 16.04 don't cooperate with 2 additional monitors

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

My Dell XT3 (256 SSD, i5-2520m, 8GB DDR3) doesn't cooperate with 2 additional monitors - TV Sharp (on HDMI) + some old AOC monitor (on VGA).

He cooperate with **both of that devices separately**, but if both are connected to laptop, only AOC is working.

In the configuration - Laptop + TV + monitor - laptop see both devices in "Screens" in "Settings" but don't cooperate with TV. (sorry for Polish menu - but I thing everything is on graphic)

What should I do to have working laptop + 2 screens?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't know if link to screen shot is available. If not -> here you are: iDOTstackDOTimgurDOTcom/0xeyuDOTpng

Comment: I've embedded your screenshot for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dell XT3 uses an old Intel 3000 graphics chip, that is wired in a way that only two screens can be active at any point in time. So as long as you use the built-in screen, you can use only one of the external connectors at a time.

If you buy the E-dock, you get 2x DVI for external displays, but the built-in screen is switched off if both are active.

So: 2 Screens only, hardware limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Your processor ([i5-2520M](https://ark.intel.com/products/52229/Intel-Core-i5-2520M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz)) has onboard graphics, so unless you have a discreet video card as well, you are limited by the processor's support.

This processor has Intel HD Graphics 3000, which is only able to support two displays at once - for example: internal + external... or external + external.

The information is available on the Intel ARK site, [here](https://ark.intel.com/products/52229/Intel-Core-i5-2520M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz)

[image]

You can't run all three displays without an extra adapter, like a USB → VGA dongle. (Note that performance is often poor for such devices).